# Getting the values of HTML Data attributes with Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, this, custom-data-attribute

I have a click function that passes the following dom as this:

```
<span class="tcloud label label-large label-primary" data-c="1" data-n="environment">
                        environment
                      </span>
```

How can I use jquery to select for the values of the html5 data attributes?

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $('span.tcloud').click(

  function () {
  console.log(this) // returns the above dom
  console.log($(this)) // returns an error
  console.log(this.data("data-c")) // returns Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLSpanElement> has no method 'data'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I simply use

```
var values = $("element").attr("data-c");
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLSpanElement> has no method 'attr'

 console.log(this.attr("data-c"))

Answer (score 0):

you can get the value by using its id in following way.

```
 $('span.tcloud').click(

  function () {
      console.log( $('#element').val());
 }
```